# YouTube Network Partnership Needed for Minecraft Tutorials?

Tags: youtube, webvideos, video-game

Copyrights around video games videos are complex.  If I want to create and post tutorials for a video game on YouTube (specifically Minecraft), do I need to have a partnership with a YouTube Network?

Comment: Where did you hear this?  The only thing I am aware of is that some companies, such as Nintendo, will submit take down notices for footage from their games if you aren't press affiliated, but that's them specifically, not anything that I'm aware of Youtube doing systematically.

Comment: By the way, down vote is because the question isn't clear in it's current state.  I'll remove it if you can clarify what you're asking so that we can make it a more useful question.

Comment: (This isn't a real answer. It's just info.) I've been making YouTube videos since 2006, but I don't do gaming vids so this information is second-hand. What I heard is that your video MAY be flagged for copyright infringement if it uses someone else's content -- either videogame visuals or the music from the game. If you're in a network (especially a gaming one like Machinima), they have agreements with the copyright owners. Tha can eliminate the copyright claims ... but check with the networks you're thinking of joining.

Answer (score 2):

For Minecraft you don't need to be on a Youtube Network.

Mojang says you can [monetize](https://help.mojang.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1389657-youtube-monetization) your Minecraft Youtube videos.

Even if you use the game's [music](http://c418.org/?p=281) in it *(however you can't use the music outside the video).*

The Minecraft [EULA](https://account.mojang.com/documents/minecraft_eula) says:

> If you upload videos of the game to video sharing and streaming sites
>   you are however allowed to put ads on them.

And the Mojang [brand guidelines](https://account.mojang.com/documents/brand_guidelines) says:

> You are allowed to put footage of our game on YouTube or any other
>   website. In fact, we like you doing so. 
>   ...
>   ...
>   you may make money using your videos of our game by, for instance,
>   through ad revenue, as long as you also add your own unique content
>   to the video, such as audio
>   commentary.

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on the policies of the game manufacturer and what they tell Youtube to do.  Some game makers claim copyright over any content produced using their game.  Some do not allow any video to be posted, some allow only videos from certain networks, some allow videos from anyone as long as they aren't monetized and some allow anyone to post videos regardless of monetization.

We can't speak to the policy of any particular video game maker.  You would have to inquire with them what they consider to be allowed or you could simply make a video and post it and see if it gets a take down notice.  There is no blanket YouTube policy that I'm aware of though, they just take down content if a take down request is submitted.  (They also do have some automatic filters for detecting music in clips that have previously been taken down.)

Comment: And let me emphasize something @AJHenderson wrote:  "some allow only videos from certain networks". To put it another way, some networks (like Machinima) have agreements with certain gaming companies that allow you to upload their copyrighted content. That doesn't apply to all networks, and it doesn't apply to all companies. But it's worth noting.

Comment: Having said this, Minecraft's EULA specifically states it's ok to post commercial (monetised) videos - BUT CHECK FOR YOURSELF!